# CQ5 constructing href of uploaded pdf

Tags: aem

I used xtype hmtl5smartfile to upload a pdf.
once it uploaded, the page content structure as follows :

[image]

Now, I am trying to iterate all the pdf pages and construct `<a href='PDF PATH' />`

Could anyone tell me, what would be the href pdf path here ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Download](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/foundation/Download.html) class to get the link for the file from your resource object.

The most simplest piece of JSP code for the same would be

```
<% Download dld = new Download(resource);
if(dld.hasContent()) { %>
    <a href="<%= dld.getHref() %>"><%= dld.getTitle(true) %></a>
<% } %>
```